# PHP small change of image

Tags: php, gd

I want to have the same image with different md5 (md5_file). How to do this ? I don't want resize image. Maybe add one pixel in random place (but how) ?

Comment: If the format you use has EXIF information, like JPGs, or other metadata, you could change that too... Then the image wouldn'tchange. I think that doesn't require much processing power

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to do that?

Comment: Take a pixel, change its rgb(x,y,z) to rgba(x,y,z,1)

Comment: @MichaelSazonov Will that have an effect on JPGs, where alpha is not stored? Thinking twice: due to repackaging, it is almost sure that the md5 will be different...

Comment: @Jack I want to test blocking spam pictures on my site.

Comment: @ppeterka Oops. Didn't notice the JPG. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should take a random pixel and adjust its rgb(x,y,z) to rgb(x,y,z+1)? This won't have a visual affect on the picture.

Comment: @ppeterka I want to change picture million times so I think better solution is change random pixel (random color). I have found this function imagesetpixel().

Comment: So, where is your current code?